# Altering the type of a menu item to local task (tab)

Tags: routes, privatemsg

I've searched for hours but I can't find a good answer on how to alter the type of a menu item to local task (tab).

The private messages 7.x module (when aided by privatemsg_filter) exposes the following tabs (local tasks):

- Inbox (/messages)
- Sent Messages (/messages/sent)
- All Messages (/messages/list)

There is a 4th menu item (/messages/new) which is currently a MENU_LOCAL_ITEM and I want to make it a local task as well. But how? And what is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

The following hack worked, to create a new local task item with definitions identical to the original menu item except it's a local task. But is it the optimal way?

```
<?
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MOMODULE_menu() {
  $items['messages/newmessage'] = array(
    'title'            => 'Write new message',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'   => array('privatemsg_new', 2, 3, NULL),
    // 'file'             => 'privatemsg.pages.inc',
    'access callback'  => 'privatemsg_user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('write privatemsg'),
    'type'             => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight'           => 5,
    'menu_name'        => 'user-menu',
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Comment: You should use [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) instead. E.g.: `$items['messages/newmessage']['type'] = MENU_LOCAL_TASK;

Comment: @znerol This is the correct answer. I was just about the write an answer to recommend that. You'd better write this as answer an get some points.

Comment: Thanks @znerol, Can I also add a css class to the tab using this hook? (if I have the menu_class module installed)

Comment: @Druvision: AFAIK at least on Drupal 7 you do not need to have any third-party modules installed in order to inject attributes to menu-items. `$items['messages/newmessage']['options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'my-class';` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @zenrol, here is a code example for the correct answer:

```
<?
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Make the privatemsg new link a tab
  $items['messages/new']['type'] = MENU_LOCAL_TASK;
}
?>
```